# Php check range between 2 time variables

Tags: php, time, range

I've got an issue in checking a time range.

Example

```
<?php

$starthour = '08'; //Starting work hour
$finishhour = '23'; //Finishing work hour
$extrapaidhours = 0; //Counting extrapaying hours

if($starthour <= 5) {
    if($starthour==5) { $extrapaidhours += 5; }
    else { $extrapaidhours += 5 - $starthour; }
}

if($starthour > 22) {
    $extrapaidhours += 24 - $starthour;
}


if($finishhour <= 5) {
    if($finishhour==5) { $extrapaidhours += 5; }
    else { $extrapaidhours += 5 - $finishhour; }
}

if($finishhour > 22) {
    $extrapaidhours += 24 - $finishhour;
}

echo $extrapaidhours;
```

I'm kinda stacked, my logic is doing it wrong I think. 
I'm trying to get the hours that are between 22-05.

Perhaps somebody started to work from 21:00 till 05:00 and he has extrapaid hours within this range which are 7 hours from 22:00 till 05:00.

How can I deal with this. Thank you all.

Comment: There is the [`DateInterval` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) (in PHP 5.3 and higher).

Comment: There is a small documentation about DateInterval, googled something but can't find something appropriate.

Comment: Actually, [`DateTime::diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#example-617). What it *gives* you is a `DateInterval` object.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution.

We must consider two different cases:

first: `$starthour < $finishhour -> $starthour` and `$finishhour` are in the same day
second: `$starthour > $finishhour -> $starthour` and `$finishhour` are in two different days

This solution uses only one `if`/`else` statement and `max`/`min` functions for the rest

```
<?php
    $starthour = '08';      //Starting work hour
    $finishhour = '23';     //Finishing work hour
    $extrapaidhours = 0;    //Counting extrapaying hours

    if ($starthour < $finishhour) 
        $extrapaidhours += (min($finishhour,5)-min($starthour,5))
                        + (max($finishhour,22)-max($starthour,22));
    else
        $extrapaidhours += (5-min(5,$starthour))
                        + (24-max(22,$starthour))
                        + min(5,$finishhour)
                        +(max($finishhour,22)-22);
    echo $extrapaidhours;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to play around with less popular PHP functions and non-standard approaches:)

```
<?php
$start_hour = '19'; //Starting work hour
$finish_hour = '08'; //Finishing work hour
$extra_paid_hours = array(22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5); //list of extra paid hours

if ($start_hour <= $finish_hour) {
    $hours = range(intval($start_hour), intval($finish_hour));
} else {
    $hours = array_merge(range(intval($start_hour), 23), range(0, intval($finish_hour)));
}

$extra_paid_hours_count = array_reduce($hours, function($accum, $hour) use($extra_paid_hours) {
        $accum += in_array($hour, $extra_paid_hours) ? 1 : 0;
        return $accum;
    }, 0);

echo $extra_paid_hours_count;
```